# Transitive verbs

Tags: grammaticality

can you provide me with a few examples wherein a transitive verb (not phrasal verbs used transitively or transitive verbs with to infinitive) immediately succeeded by a prepositional phrase? 
With regards
Syam Kumar

Answer (score 1):

I gave to my younger brother some short-sleeved shirts I no longer wear.

He passed to his hunting buddy a large mason jar full of moonshine.

She has taken to the dry-cleaners that silk blouse on which you spilled a cup of coffee.  You should offer to pay for the cleaning.

This computer can solve in a fraction of a second even the most complicated of differential equations.

The basketball player saw out of the corner of his eye his teammate standing free at the top of the key.