# Should I change the position of these clauses to make the sentence fluent

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, style

I wrote this sentence in an article (scientific)

> In order to force the students to rely on their phonics knowledge, instead of depending on their memory, to do the tests, the teacher can add some unfamiliar words, which are not usually shown on the textbooks, to the list.

Is it considered a long sentence for a scientific article? Or for a native speaker, Or in any aspect you may consider.

If you feel the question is for proofreading my main question is below:

I feel there is a gap between "add some .." and "to the list".
To resolve it, could I say

> ... the teacher can add some unfamiliar words to the list, which are not usually shown on the textbooks.

Or maybe better

> ... the teacher can add to the list some unfamiliar words, which are not usually shown on the textbooks.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean with "does this sentence _count long_"?

Comment: When testing, the teacher can add unfamiliar words to force the students to rely on their knowledge of phonics rather than their memory of individual words.

Comment: @oerkelens I edited my question, long to a, say, native speaker, or in an article

Comment: It isn't the length as much as the optimal location of clauses and the elimination of unnecessary verbiage that one should be concerned about.

Comment: What @TRomano said. The original isn't so much "long" as "badly phrased". As a general principle a sentence (of any length) will be clearer if it starts with the main subject/verb (*the teacher / add words* in this case). And is there really any point in explicitly mentioning that these words are *not usually shown on the textbooks*, as well as being called *unfamiliar*, for example?

Comment: If you wanted to get all of what you wrote into one sentence: "When testing, the teacher can add *to the list* unfamiliar words *which do not usually appear in textbooks*, in order to force the students to rely on their knowledge of phonics rather than their memory of individual words."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think a definition is necessary, because maybe the reader couldn't get what could be an "unfamiliar word"

Comment: @TRomano Thank you but I feel your last suggestion lost the emphasis order. Actually, the list is prepared by the teacher before testing and for the software. As I want to describe features of the software I think "in order to ..." fits better

Comment: There is no emphasis without clarity, Ahmad.  "When testing" does not imply "at the exact moment of presenting the test to the student" but "in the context of testing".

Comment: If you really feel it's important to define "unfamiliar word" more closely, you should probably consider doing that in a separate sentence. You're just trying to cram too many (loosely) related concepts into a single utterance.

Comment: I think I understand the question better after your edit, but _count long_ is not grammatical. I **guess** you mean to ask _is this considered a long sentence_ or _would a native speaker consider this sentence (too) long_.

Comment: @oerkelens: I think Ahmad was concerned about how much 'tundra' there was between "add" and "to the list".  In my reply, I repositioned the prepositional phrase to keep the conceptual unit ('add to the list') contiguous.. See this question, which was closed (http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60432/transitive-verbs/60443#60443)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too long, if that's what you mean, but you have too many commas and a couple of redundant words:

> In order to force the students to rely on their phonics knowledge
>   instead of their memory to do the tests, the teacher can add some
>   unfamiliar words which are not usually shown in the textbooks.

Comment: +1 for eliminating the unneeded "instead of depending on"

Comment: Thank you, In your version you omitted "to the list", but the way I used it I think I had to put "which are not usually shown in the textbooks" between a comma pair. Right?

Comment: Well, if by 'to the list' you mean 'to the test', then I think that's implied by he context. You could also say '..the teacher can add to them some unfamiliar words which are not...'